# Which type of power boat do I need for overnight trips?

Tags: boats

I'm an absolute beginner about boats, but let's say I want to buy a boat to use in the canals of my city (Amsterdam), but also for "long" trips, to other cities, coasts. Trips that require days to reach the destination, so I need it to be covered for nights.

What kind of boat could I buy (I'm talking about cheap boats, possibly priced few thousand of euros?

I'm interested in knowing what type of boat I do need and how big, how many feet/meters...

Comment: You are just to late for the Hiswa, which ended yesterday: http://www.hiswarai.nl/Pages/default.aspx. That would be the best venue to get an answer for your question

Comment: Keep in mind that if you want to handle your boat by yourself without a license there are some limitations to the length and power of the boat (in The Netherlands). If the boat is under 15m long and can not reach speeds above 20km/h [you don't need a license](http://www.vaarbewijzen.nl/varen-zonder.html) (link in Dutch).

Comment: @BartArondson: how does it 20km/h limit apply to sailboats? I theory you could have catamaran shorter than 15m, which could sail >20km/h.

Comment: @vartec I don't know, the link specifically mentions a boat + engine. The [Dutch wikipedia on the ICC (boat license)](http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaarbewijs) states that kids under the age of 12 can sail a boat shorter than 7m without a license.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That question can lead to a very complex answer because there is no simple answer.

I am going to keep it short, but notice that you probably can't do all kind of trips in a boat like this.

You will be needing a boat with a cabin, to be able to sleep, have a toilet and a micro kitchen.

In general the larger the boat, more stable it is under rough weather/ waves. You should also consider which type of weather you want to face and how confortable/safe you want to be.

[This](http://nl.topboats.com/barcos-ocasion/aquamar-bahia-20-cabin-lancha-suzuki-115-cv) is probably the smallest and cheapest for your goal.

Comment: Your "this" link is dead.  Can you replace it with a short description?

Comment: While this was the accepted answer, it seems the price tag of a boat like that is going to be more than "a few thousand of euros". At that price point I was expecting something more like a tent on a boat https://www.google.com/search?q=tent+on+boat&tbm=isch . The important safety thing though is getting a bigger, more seaworthy boat "for 'long' trips, to other cities, coasts". The ability to sleep, cook, and bathroom can be added to almost any boat of sufficient size with camping equipment. FYI the link goes to boats like https://www.google.com/search?q=Aquamar+Bahia+20+Cabin&tbm=isch